# Selecting rows based value in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with customer ID and Order value. Single customer can have multiple orders.
So i want to select only the customer who has more than 1000$ order value across the orders.

Here is the sample table

```
CutomerID       OrderID       OrderValue
========================================
100             1             500
100             2             6000
200             3             1500
200             4             2000
```

So I want to get only the Customer ID 200 with his sales value summed up as 3500.
Since Customer 100 doest not have a sales value more than 1000 across his orders.

Please let me know how to write a query for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to exclude all customers that DO have at least one OrderValue less than 1000?

Comment: 6000 is more than 1000, unless I'm missing something. Maybe you meant 600?

Comment: Kapol, I meant 6000 only, I want to exclude customer 100 because he does not have order value more than 1000 in his both the order, refer order id 1 and 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using subquery to select all `CustomerID` that has at least one order having order value < 1000, then get sum of orders for all `CustomerID` that is not selected in the subquery :

```
SELECT CustomerID, SUM(OrderValue) 
FROM MyTable
WHERE CustomerID NOT IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID WHERE OrderValue > 1000)
GROUP BY CustomerID
```